# Install HorizontalPodAutoscaler (HPA) using Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'd like to do all k8s installation, configuration, and maintenance using Helm v3 (v3.7.2).

Thus I have setup yaml templates for:

- deployment
- configmap
- service
- ingress

Yet I can't find any information in the Helm v3 docs on setting up an HPA (*HorizontalPodAutoscaler*). Can this be done using an hpa.yaml that pulls from values.yaml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Example, try `helm create nginx` will create a template project call "nginx", and inside the "nginx" directory you will find a templates/hpa.yaml example. Inside the values.yaml -> autoscaling is what control the HPA resources:

```
autoscaling:
  enabled: false  # <-- change to true to create HPA
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 100
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
  # targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage: 80
```

Comment: targetCPUUtilizationPercentage and targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage are no longer in Kubernetes HPA specification

Comment: See *apiVersion: autoscaling/v1*. For newer cluster should use *autoscaling/v2*. However, the answer was based on `helm create` command, not strictly about latest HPA spec.

Answer (score 4):

> Can this be done using an hpa.yaml that pulls from values.yaml?

Yes. [HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/) is a native Kubernetes resource that you can template out just like you have done for your other resources. Helm is both a package management system and a templating tool, but it is unlikely its docs contain specific examples for all Kubernetes API objects.

You can see many examples of HPA templates in the [Bitnami Helm Charts](https://github.com/bitnami/charts). For example, apache has an [`hpa.yaml`](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/apache/templates/hpa.yaml) that is templated-out if `.Values.autoscaling.enabled`.